# How to externally link to nuxt js app and load contentful api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, contentful

I have a nuxt js app that when linked to from an external source loads the page but does not call the api to pull through the dynamic content.

The api loads fine when using `<nuxt-link>` from within the site and the server config seems correct as the page loads (header, footer etc).

I know about the generate property in nuxt.config, but would this not just create static pages of all the content currently in contentful rather than making the call upon loading the page.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-generate/

Comment: Too vague. Please add code

Comment: Hello @Aldarund, there is no specific code that could be pinpointed that is causing the problem.

Comment: From your description its impossible to tell anything

Comment: I'm having the same issue at the moment. any luck fixing it?

Comment: Sorry for the delay I used SSR and a node server